# Is there a good way to make a draggable and droppable object by using jQuery without jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make something draggable and droppable without using jQuery UI, but I can't seem to find anyone who hasn't used the UI. Do you guys happen to know of any way to accomplish this without using the UI?

Answered my own question:

```
$('#div2').on('dragover', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#drag1').on('dragleave', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("#div2").on('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#popup').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500); 
});
$('#div3').on('dragover', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("#div3").on('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#popup-cart').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500); 
});
```

Comment: I've tried HTML5 drag/drop and I found it tough to accomplish all my goals and ended up with JQuery UI.  It's got some quirks too, but it's overall more robust than native options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question:

```
$('#div2').on('dragover', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#drag1').on('dragleave', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("#div2").on('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#popup').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500); 
});
$('#div3').on('dragover', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("#div3").on('drop', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();  
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#popup-cart').fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is unreasonable. It might be alright in something like React or Angular, but with plain jQuery... have fun!

But in all seriousness you would have to handle the down click, and while the click is down, handle mouse drags, and set the `top: x` and `left: y` values to the mouse position. Then stop dragging on mouse up click. Like I said, much easier in React, where you get `states` and can re-render singular components quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is drag&drop support in html5 -  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

so you can use that together with jquery without jq UI

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Codepen submission I found the other day.

I haven't looked too deeply into it, but you can probably take inspiration from the events and positioning.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/mayurbirle/pen/LyQejQ)

```
//Add Event Listener
function adding()
{
    dragme.addEventListener('mousedown',mousedown,false);
    body.addEventListener('mouseup',mouseup,false);
}
```

SO won't let me post codepen links without code, so here is a random snippet of som eventlisteners.